# Existe uma maneira de usar Processamento de Linguagem Natural (NLP) pra transformar strings em inteiros?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Vi alguns [exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) de códigos pra transformar strings como, por exemplo, "quatro" em um inteiro 4, mas era sempre bastante manual. Tem alguma forma mais automática de fazer isso usando NLP?

Uma coisa que notei quando fiz o teste abaixo foi que o `spacy`reconhece tanto "quatro" quanto "4" como números, o que já é um bom começo, mas tem como usar isso pra fazer a transformação de um tipo para o outro? Eu não entendo muito de processamento de linguagem natural, então não sei exatamente qual o nome da técnica que seria responsável por isso.

```py
nlp = spacy.load("pt")

doc = nlp("quatro vídeos")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
# retorna 
# quatro NUM nummod
# vídeos SYM ROOT

doc = nlp("4 vídeos")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
# retorna 
# 4 NUM nummod
# vídeos SYM ROOT
```

Obrigada!

Comment: Uma forma "mais robusta" e "mais consistente" pode ter - mas "mais automática" eu duvido  - NLP e outras técnicas vão envolver cofiguração e parametrizações que sempre vão ser mais complexas odo que um match com dicionário `{'zero': 0, 'um': 1, ...}` A leitura de números maiores escritos por exenso ("dois mil cento e setenta e três"), acho que sim, pode ser feita de forma mais simples (automatica) com NLP do que com uma heuristica comum só com `if` e `dicionários`. Mas para um único  dígito, certamente não vai ser a opção mais simples (embora possa ser melhor por vários outros motivos)

Comment: entendi. o que eu fiz pra resolver meu problema foi justamente criar um dicionário, mas eu teria que ficar infinitamente digitando pra conseguir cobrir todos os casos possíveis. você pode me dar um exemplo dessas técnicas mais consistentes que de fato usam NLP?

Answer (score 0):

não acredito que seja utilizado NLP para resolver este problema. As principais utilizações de NLP são para tradução de texto, geração de texto, geração de legenda para imagens... Atualmente, para resolver esses problemas utiliza-se Redes Neurais Recorrentes (RNN), que são redes neurais profundas que possuem um custo alto para serem treinadas.

Acredito que a forma mais simples de resolver esse problema é realmente utilizar um dicionário. Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) existem vários exemplos de código em python que resolvem o problema. Você só vai precisar traduzir as palavras do dicionário para o português.

Espero ter ajudado, caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre aplicações de NLP pode perguntar :)